# JSON Data Not Parsed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i am Newbie in iOS Development. I want to Parse an JSON Data From My WebServices for that I have written folliwing code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/latest_post.php?page=%d",pageNum]];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});

}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;
    self.json= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.navuArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.navuTable reloadData];
         NSLog(@"JSON Data %@",self.navuArray);
    }
    self.navuTable.hidden=FALSE;
}
```

Here `Self.json` is A JSON Dictionary and `self.navuArray` is my `NSMutableArray` when i print my Array then It returns Num. Please Give me Solution for it.

Comment: @vishnu when i print like as 'NSLog(@"JSON Data %@",self.navuArray);' then it Return "JSON Data (null)"

Comment: Check if there is any error. Log your error variable in case when array is nil.

Comment: i saw the response now. data is an array. in that objects will be present post_id, post_title etc...

Comment: @vishnu when i write a code like as
 if (responsedata.length > 0)
    {
        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        self.navuArray=[json objectForKey:@"data"];
    }
    NSLog(@"JSOn Array %@",self.navuArray);
then it give me my JSON Parsing array.

Comment: Does your `self.json` contains accurate data after its initialization?

Comment: @Zen Yes my self.json Contain accurate data after initialisation.

Comment: @Ramesh Then its your `navuArray` that must be un-initialised.

Comment: @Zen Yes it is thinks For that.I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its your `navuArray` that is not initialized before you are adding objects to it from array. Initialize it before you call for your data and then add objects to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
  table = [[UITableView alloc]init];

    [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *array = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
     for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
     {

        dict1 = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        [postIdArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"post_id]];
        [postTitleArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"post_title"]];
        [postTitleSlungArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"post_title_slug"]];
        NSString *dateId = [dict objectForKey:@"post_date"];
        NSArray *dateArray = [dateId componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        [dateArrs addObject:[dateArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [timeArrs addObject:[dateArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        //[dateIdArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"date"]];
        [postViewsArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"post_views"]];
        [imageArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"feature_image"]];
        [shortArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"short_description"]];
        [nameArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"author_name"]];


    }
```

Comment: @vishu Here my Webservice Contain pagi nation so what about second page?